# Do laptop chargers still consume electricity when the laptop is turned off (shut down) and the charger is plugged in

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I tend to forget that I am charging my laptop when I turn it off and leave it overnight charging, even though it is turned off. I'm wondering, does it still consume electricity?

Answer (score 1):

It won’t be a significant amount, but yes it will consume a small amount of electricity even if the machine is off. The battery slowly loses charge and has to be replenished, some chargers have lights on them that use a small amount of energy, etc.

Comment: This isn’t an answer, but rather a comment. The question itself is also a [dupe of this older question](https://superuser.com/q/340108/167207) since this topic is not a new one.

Comment: ? it was a yes or no question - I not only answered the question but I also provided details.

Comment: This is utterly not a test or no question is all based on speculation. This is a duplicate question as well as being opinion-based. Not all chargers and laptops work the same way. Thus this question is vague has heck. Would my Apple MacBook charger drain the same wall a Dell laptop charger does? What about models; does behavior change between make and models. Thus the reason I stated, “This isn’t an answer, but rather a comment.”

Comment: I'll give you that it's not a good question but standby loss and battery charge cycles are pretty much a universal concept with laptop chargers. I really don't see the issue here.

Comment: The issue is your answer is a comment. Not an answer. Simple as that. And the question is a duplicate. So posting an answer got a bad question that is also vague and a duplicate only encourages stuff like this. Your answer posted as a comment would never have been an issue. But as an answer, it is an issue. PS: “… but standby loss and battery charge cycles are pretty much a universal concept with laptop chargers.” But does it operate the same way nowadays with smart chargers and even smarter laptops that might shut off charging completely overnight? It is simply not a clear issue nowadays.